# Android layout not being aligned to top

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have a `RelativeLayout` that, at the moment, holds an `ImageView` which I would like to to have aligned to the top right of the screen, and then later another `ImageView` to the top left. However, at the moment, the `RelativeLayout` that is suppsoed to hold these, is not aligned to the top of the screen for some reason.

I have the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#a6c"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/frontFragment"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frontText"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/infoIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" issue here
            android:src="@drawable/info" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frontDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="some value"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frontCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="another value"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but the output looks like the following

[image]

Comment: If you're looking to set the images side by side then you can use the grid view or gridlayout with row and column count

Comment: your `LinearLayout` has `android:gravity="bottom"` use better `ConstraintLayout` instead of LinearLayout and RelativeLayout to receive your approach

Comment: I think [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) is much easier to use than RelativeLayout. I know this doesn't answer the question but I think you need to try it. Google recommend it.

Comment: You have the frontText TextView at the top.

Comment: @forpas ahh good catch! moving my relative layout before that textview brings my image view to the top now. However, how i can get the imageview closer to the end of the screen? doing android:paddingRight="10dp" doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: The only padding I see in your code is: `android:padding="16dp"` for the parent LinearLayout. Remove it.

Comment: Your info image src have some extra space in right and left.you can see that image view  layout by click on the image   and you set wrap content as width so i believe if you set correct image src it will work .nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: can you not see that gravity is set to  bottom on the linear layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments that with `ConstraintLayout` you can do it more easily without nesting the layouts.

As following, Just replace with your content(icons/text):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_selected" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frontDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="some value"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frontCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="another value"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Following is the result:

[image: ConstraintLayout]

Comment: just want to mention that in the end i also had to change from app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" to android:src="@drawable/ic_add" for the image to actually show up on the device when running.

Answer (score 1):

Remove android:gravity="bottom" from in linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#a6c"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/frontFragment"
    >
```

to :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#a6c"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/frontFragment"
    >
```

Comment: thanks, that is actually one of the changes i had to make, but now the bottom textviews are gone completely.

Comment: can you post the output you want. it seems like you're still new with how the XML layouts work in android studio. you probably missing some constraints like "layout:weight".